# Problem with iAd integration?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad, iad

I have a problem with iAd integration in my iPhone application? after adding ADBannerView in xib its not showing any error at run time and it not displayed in the view.

I also tried this by anagrammatically but still I have same problem  ?

Can any one guide me how to integrate iAd in iphone application ??

Thanks in advance..

Comment: can you help in  this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5947552/how-to-display-test-iad-banner-in-the-simulator

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can try this tutorial:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/1371/how-to-integrate-iad-into-your-iphone-app

Answer (score 0):

You can find the sample code of iAd and all the details are given in iAd programming guide. visit http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/navigation/index.html?section=Resource+Types&topic=Sample+C#section=Frameworks&topic=iAd